# Crear un Campo imput y que genere un link en base a lo que la persona puso en el cmapo

Tags: php, html

Hola necesito crear algo como un formulario que tenga 2 campos.
Nombre:
Apellido:

y un boton "enviar"

Lo que necesito es que cuando se aprete el boton enviar vaya a una web especifica www.XXXXXX.com/"nombreapellido"

pero sin las referencias del nombre de los campos

pongo un ejemplo porque no se si se entendio

Tengo
Campo1 Nombre: Carlos
Campo2 Apellido: Garcia

Boton "Enviar"

Al apretar deberia generar un link que sea "www.XXXXXX.com/CarlosGarcia"

Gracias

Comment: Hola, te ayudo con mucho gusto pero antes ¿podrías subir el código de los campos y el botón que tienes hasta ahora? ademas de mejorar un poco la calidad de la pregunta, ya sabes, los usuarios no deben contestar preguntas de baja calidad.

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo el ejemplo de Lee Chevarria

Tienes que colocar el  siguiente código en la etiqueta `script`:

```
/// #form es el id de tu formulario

    $("#form").submit(function( event ) {  
      event.preventDefault(); //   cancela el envió del formulario  
      var nombre = $(".nombre").val(); // obtienes el valor del input del formulario con la clase nombre 
      var apellido = $(".apellido").val();  // obtienes el valor del input del formulario con la clase apellido 
      var url = "http://www.XXXXXX.com/"+nombre+apellido;   
      location.href = url  // redireccion a la url que necesitas  
    });
```

Todo esto utilizando **JQUERY**.

Answer (score 0):

algo asi creo que puede ser...

```
$("#form").submit(function( event ) {
    var nombre = $(".nombre").val();
    var apellido = $(".apellido").val();
    var url = "www.XXXXXX.com/"+nombre+apellido; 
    $(location).attr('href',url);
});
```

podrias variar la forma de llamar a la funcion... de acuerdo a tu formulario...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta rapida, ese codigo lo pongo en un archivo .php o donde, perdon soy un 0 con esto de programacion y necesito hacer eso.
Gracias

Comment: es utilizando JQUERY...